# Jackson- Json parsing failure because of extra quotes in values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am struggling to convert json string to java object using jackon. This might be duplicate question but I couldn't find any solution for this problem:

Here's json string:

```
{
"hierCD":"B",
"category":"C",
"id":"ty8lre",
"bca":"8543289",
"companyName":""not listed"",
"productLineCD":"CARD"
}
```

Java Bean:

```
public class HierAttributes{
protected String id;
protected String bca;
protected String companyName;
protected String productLineCD;
protected String hierCD;
protected String category;
}
```

Trying to convert json to object using jackson this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
mapper.readValue(nodeStr, HierAttributes.class);
```

I get below exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: {"hierCD":"B","category":"C","id":"ty8lre","bca":"8543289","companyName":""not listed"","productLineCD":"CARD"}; line: 1, column: 77]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1957)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:770)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
```

is there any way so jackson will escape additional quotes in field value(`""not listed""`) while parsing? how to resolve this parsing issue?

Comment: Never had to do this in Jackson, but will the normal `\"` not work...?  IE `"\"not listed\""`

Comment: That is invalid json.

Comment: yeah, it's invalid json, how to escape only those extra quotes  ?

Comment: Jackson won't parse invalid JSON (except in one specific case, not this one).

Comment: @Sotirios, to make it valid json i need to add escape extra quotes, how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Parse the String and correct it. That has nothing to do with Jackson, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: @RahulSharma - For future reference - You can use tools like JSONLint to validate your JSON - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Sotirios- I have updated json string. does jackson provide any solution to escape additional quotes?

Comment: I still do not understand why you can't just escape the extra quotes with backslash...?  The JSON is valid at that point...

Comment: > Here's json string

No, it actually isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First

Accept that this is not valid JSON and you will have to alter it before jackson will parse it for you.

Second

If doubling of double quotes is the only problem, then preprocess the string with one of the following before passing it to jackson:

1. Remove the double quoting: `newValue = initialValue.replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");`
2. Add backslash to the inner quotes.  `newValue2 = StringUtils.replace(initialValue, "\"\"", "\"\\\"");`

I suggest using Apache Commons Lang3 StringUtils for option 2 above.

Comment: Since, it is JSON so i should not escape any of the fields' begin and end quotes, I only have to escape quotes which are inside value. I am not certain about the pattern of quotes, the position of quotes can be anywhere inside field value.So what should be pattern to replace it?