# jackson library to accept currency and percent as valid json

Tags: json, scala, jackson, serialization

```
 val jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject("{\"name\":\"abc\",\"Estd date\":\"23.06.1995\",\"GrowthRate\":50%}")
 println(jsonObject)
 new ObjectMapper().readTree("{\"name\":\"abc\",\"Estd date\":\"23.06.1995\",\"GrowthRate\":50%}")

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
```

What can be done to have the same behavior as that of JSONObject? We have some restrictions due to which we cannot use JSONObject. Any help with this?

Is there a way we can do this using custom serializer? Currency symbols like $50 should also be parsed.

I am using jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions like `50%` or `10$` must be transported as string [1].

```
new ObjectMapper().readTree("{\"name\":\"abc\",\"Estd date\":\"23.06.1995\",\"GrowthRate\":\"50%\"}")
```

will work.

---

[1]

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names: false null true

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-5

Related:

- [What is the standard for formatting currency values in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249406/what-is-the-standard-for-formatting-currency-values-in-json)
- [Jackson- Json parsing failure because of extra quotes in values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353487/jackson-json-parsing-failure-because-of-extra-quotes-in-values)

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how JSONObject parses it by default as a string. Is there any configuration by default which treats these values by default as a string ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe ask this as a new question?! I think I would preprocess the not-Json with some regexp/string-replace. At the same time I would ask the producer to provide valid Json.